# Передача параметров на страницу через router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Есть данные которые хранятся в свойстве `data` App.vue в этом же файле установлены router-link на другие страницы. Вопрос как мне передать данные из `data` в страницы которые привязаны с помощью router-link

Comment: Передавай через пропсы маршрута - они автоматически попадают в одноименные пропсы связанного с ним компонента (указанного в свойстве `component` объекта route в конфиге роутера). В оф. документации это подробно описано.

Comment: @yar85 можешь кинуть ссылку на документацию, а то запарка))..спасибо за совет!)

Comment: [Раз](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/passing-props.html) ([v4](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html)) и [два](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/api/#%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-router-link).

Comment: @yar85 спасибо огромно!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$router.push(name: <router-name>, params: { <param-key>: <param-value> })
```